# How to split a string based on multiple criteria in Ruby

Tags: ruby, split

I have the following problem in my Ruby program:

```
def prompt(*input)
  print *input
  gets.strip()
end

def what_up(greeting, bros)
  bros.each { |bro| puts "What up #{bro}!"}
end

friends = (prompt "List all of your friends, separate them by commas!").split(HELP)

what_up("What up", friends)
```

I want to split the inputted string by commas; however, due to variances in user input I want to be able to split based on "," or ", "

Everything I've been able to find is talking about syntax such as /\s|,/ etc; however, this syntax does not seem to take into account anything in quotations. I tried using /\W/ also, which split the string into an array of words and spaces. I could use this but do not know how to get rid of " " in an array that looks like this:

```
["Hello", " ", "Great", " ", "World"]
```

that turns into

```
["Hello", "Great", "World"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reject any empty strings from the resulting array, the following works for me:

```
"hurp,durp, foo, bar,baz".split(/\W/).reject(&:empty?) # => ["hurp", "durp", "foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
"Foo,bar, foo,  bar".split(",").map(&:strip) # => ["Foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Humpty,  Dumpty,sat on a     wall"

str.split(/,\s*/) 
  #=> ["Humpty", "Dumpty", "sat on a", "wall"]
```

This regular expression ("regex") reads, "Match a comma followed by zero or more (`*`) whitespace characters (`\s`)" (here just spaces).

See [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html).

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! Works perfectly!

I am new to all of these shorthands that are being used inside of the parenthesis. Could you link to a site that helps explain these and their syntax? Or explain the \s* and what it is that it's doing?

Comment: The regular expression ("regex") reads, "match a comma followed by zero or more (`*`) whitespace characters (`\s`)" (here just spaces). See [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html).

Comment: @Coatless, please do not edit answers merely to impose your preferences for style. For one, you moved my sentence, "This regular..." so that it appeared at the beginning, before the regex to which it refers has been defined. That makes no sense to me.

Comment: @CarySwoveland as it stood, the explanation was in the comment and it came up on the low-quality post delete queue. As an explanation was prevalent, I added it to the post to avoid it from reappearing. Apologies for placing it over vs. under.